# How do I get a fail case to pass in Xcode UITests with swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, assertions, xcode-ui-testing

Context: Just starting to get into automation. Unfortunately, my only practice app has a changing UI. E.g., I have buttons that are hidden for some users, and shown for others depending on access permission levels.

Goal: What I want to test is when a fail is a pass; that the buttons are indeed absent when they should be. I have overlays and stuff to contend with too, but I think I can extrapolate from a button example once I'm shown how to do it.

Before this section, the login tests have already passed. This person cannot see sometimesHiddenButton, so I need it to pass the fact that it can't find the button, not fail it. How do I tell it to do that? Is there a special kind of assert I can use, or conditionals, or what?

```
let tablesQuery = app.tables
app.navigationBars["LandingScreen"].buttons["Hamburger"].tap()
  tablesQuery.staticTexts["alwaysShownButton"].tap()

app.navigationBars["alwaysAccessibleScreen"].buttons["Hamburger"].tap()
  tablesQuery.staticTexts["sometimesHiddenButton"].staticTexts.tap() <-fails
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.exists` param is definitely the one you want - I think the problem is that you are calling `.exists` on `.staticTexts` instead of on the XCUIElement returned by `.staticTexts["sometimesHiddenButton"]` 
this:

```
tablesQuery.staticTexts["sometimesHiddenButton"].exists
```

should return you a boolean you can switch on or make assertions with.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `.exists`value.

```
if !tablesQuery.staticTexts["sometimesHiddenButton"].staticTexts.exists {
    //do something for users that don't need to see this
} else {
    //do something for users that do see the button
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says "Unary operator '!' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'XCUIElement'" when I try this.